# Strategi must be a string

Tags: yii2

please help me..
when data input arises such problems "Strategi must be a string."
this is my controller :

```
$isistrategi = $_POST['FormNarasi'];
$fn = FormNarasi::find()->where([
  'kriteria_id' => $model->id,
  'form_spmi_id' => $formSpmi->id,
])->one();  
                      
if(empty($fn))
  $fn = new FormNarasi;
$fn->kriteria_id = $model->id;
$fn->form_spmi_id = $formSpmi->id;
$fn->strategi = $isistrategi;
```

this is my _form :

```
<?php
  $fn = FormNarasi::find()->where([
    'kriteria_id' => $model->id,
    'form_spmi_id' => $formSpmi->id
  ])->one(); 

  echo $form->field($fn, 'strategi')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'advance'
  ])
?>


<div class="form-group">
  <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success','value'=>'1','name'=>'btn-submit']) ?>
</div>
    
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

please help, master

Comment: Check your model rules, the error is clear you insert a value that isn't a string. PS don't use $_POST directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are assigning an array to the model

```
$isistrategi = $_POST['FormNarasi'];
...
$fn->strategi = $isistrategi;  // HERE
```

and in the following code you are accessing it. There is an array assigned. So you should assign there a string (the content of the CKEditor)

```
echo $form->field($fn, 'strategi')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [  // HERE 
...
  ])
```

As @Sfili_81 mentioned, do not access the $_POST directly and rather use `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`

Comment: thank you very much for the information. I'll try again.